# How to include only the content of a chapter in the document?

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I am using a specially formatted thesis format called `authesis`. It includes many chapters. I want to include only the content of the chapters without the Chapter number or title name in the generated PDF. For ex, if the Chapter number is 'Chapter 1', the title is 'Introduction' and there are many subsections, the content must have only the subsections and their contents. The Chapter number and title must be absent. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: try  add`\makeatletter \let\chapter\@gobble \makeatother` as a start. You will need to redefine some counters (`\thesection, \thefigure...`)  and we need example of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a version for `book` (and probably for most other classes having  `\chapter` as structure level, however not for `memoir` (yet)).

Just saying `\let\chapter\@gobble` as touhami proposed is not enough (though a good idea!), since `\chapter` calls `\@chapter`, which usually has an optional argument)

I rather caught `\chapter` itself and redefined it slightly (requires the latest `xparse` release, however)

The counters being in the reset list of `chapter` are auto-detected and are removed from the list with `\counterwithout` in a loop done by `\loopthroughresetlist`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}


\usepackage{chngcntr}


\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_flower_reset_seq 
\NewDocumentCommand{\loopthroughresetlist}{mm}{%
  \seq_gclear:N \g_flower_reset_seq
  \group_begin:
  \cs_if_exist:cT {cl@#1} {%
    \def\@elt##1{%
      \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_flower_reset_seq {##1}
    }
    \use:c{cl@#1}% Fill the list
  }
  \group_end:
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_flower_reset_seq  {%
    \use:c{\cs_to_str:N #2}{#1}{##1}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\latex@@chapter\chapter
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{sO{#3}m}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      \latex@@chapter*{#3}%
    }{%
      \ifnogobblechapter
      \latex@@chapter[#2]{#3}
      \fi
    }%
  }
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\counterwithoutwrapper}[2]{%
  \counterwithout{#2}{#1}%
}

\newif\ifnogobblechapter
\nogobblechapterfalse

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\ifnogobblechapter
\else
\loopthroughresetlist{chapter}{\counterwithoutwrapper}
\fi

\tableofcontents

\chapter[Foo entry to ToC]{Foo Chapter}

\section{A subsection of a gobbled chapter}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Another chapter}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Another figure caption}
\end{figure}

Some other content

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Sebastiano: Thanks, I've chosen some votes for you ;-)

Comment: :-). When I see your excellent answers and several very good people like you always vote. I'll always thank you for everything you have done and are doing. You are a wonderful person.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Don't exaggerate ;-)